# Javascript: setting object properties

Tags: javascript, object, set

**I want to be able to do this:**

```
var user1 = {
  name: 'John',
  gender: 'male'
}


var user2 = {
  name: 'James',
  gender: 'male',
  email: 'james@gmail.com'
}

user1.someSetMethod({email: 'john@gmail.com'});
user2.someSetMethod({name: 'Jenny', gender: 'female'});
```

**Desired Outcome:**

```
var user1 = {
  name: 'John',
  gender: 'male',
  email: 'john@gmail.com'
}


var user2 = {
  name: 'Jenny',
  gender: 'female',
  email: 'james@gmail.com'
}
```

I want a method that will set attributes according to what is passed into the function. Is the attribute doesn't exist I want it to be created, if it does, I want it to be overwritten.

**Does a method like this exist in Javascript?**

Comment: jQuery has a very nice extend method:  http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is normally called **extending** your object.  Virtually every JavaScript library has its own method to do this.  Or you can write your own in a few lines of code.

- [jQuery extend](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/)
- [underscore.js extend](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#extend)
- [ExtJS extend](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/3-4/#!/api/Ext)
- [MooTools extend](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Core/Core#Type:extend)
- [Prototype extend](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/object/extend)

Using jQuery's method, you'd do it like so:

```
var user1 = {
  name: 'John',
  gender: 'male'
};

$.extend(user1, {
  email: 'john@gmail.com'
});

user1.email === 'john@gmail.com'; //true
```

Comment: Or in plain JS:
`var user1 = { name: 'John', gender: 'male' }; user1["email"] = "john@gmail.com";`

Answer (score 3):

No, You don't want to do this.

The only way to add a method to all objects is to extend `Object.prototype`.

Doing so (in ES3 browsers like IE8) has a consequence of adding properties to enumerations.

For example:

```
Object.prototype.extend = function (o) {
  // clone properties of o into this
};

var someObj = {};
for (var key in someObj) {
  console.log(key); // "extend"
}
```

The best you can do is use `Object.extend`

```
Object.extend(user2, {
  name: "Jenny",
  gender: "female"
});
```

[pd](https://github.com/Raynos/pd#pd.extend) has an implementation of `extend` or you can use:

```
Object.extend = function (target, source) {
  for (var key in source) {
    target[key] = source[key];
  }
};
```

Comment: @pagewil :\ I'm telling you what you want to do can't be done sensible, but you can use an alternative.

Comment: Thanks this is more detailed :)

Comment: I am actually requiring it in a NodeJS context, should have mentioned earlier really.

Comment: @pagewil `require("pd").extendNatives()` ;)

Answer (score 2):

If you are willing to use jquery, you can use it's extend method, along with some defaults that will make sure all of the properties you want are set correctly.

Something like this:

```
function whatever(obj1) {
    var defaults = {
        name: 'Foo Bar',
        email: 'email@example.com',
        gender: 'male'
    };

    return $.extend(defaults, obj1);
}
```